# How to resolve Author signature issue?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I have an app on tizen TV store and when I am trying to update version then I get the following error "**Author signature of the App you would like to register is set incorrectly. Try check your author-signature.xml file please.**"

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's check step by step....

- The package you have uploaded was generated using 'Right click on project > Build a signed package?
- Make sure you are using the same keystore than in previous app. You can find the Certificate Manager under Tools > Certificate Manager

[image]

If you have several certificates profiles and want to check which one was used to sing your published app, you can:

1. Download it from Samsung Seller (under Information for Verification > App Source)
2. Open the wgt file using 7z or similar.
3. Locate the author-signature.xml and signature1.xml files and open them using an editor (Tizen Studio, Notepad++, ...)
4. The first KeyInfo > X509Data > X509Certificate tag on author-signature.xml corresponds to author.crt file
5. The first KeyInfo > X509Data > X509Certificate tag on signature-1.xml corresponds to distributor.crt file

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is located certification manager and how to check keystore?

Comment: I've edited my answer to share some tips about how to locate and verify the wgt signatures

Comment: Thank you so much to solve my issue. In my case distributor.csr used insted of distributor.crt