# How can I find out what the signature of a wgt Tizen file for a smart tv is?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, smart-tv

I have a TV App released on the Samsung Seller store. My Tizen Studio totally crashed after an update and had to reinstall. I have copies of every certificate or related file saved up but I have no idea which file to use. I've tried a few attempts and Samsung keeps complaining that the signature is wrong, but to get that error I have to wait for them to test it, which can take days.

So my question is, how can I verify check two WGT files against each other to see if they have the right signature?

I have unzipped them and compared the `author-signature.xml` file and the `X509Certificate` values are the same, and also the same on the `signature1.xml` file, so I don't know what else it could be?

Samsung says there is no way for me to verify this on my own but surely there must be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have found a solution by yourself, but if you haven't you can check this answer

[How to resolve Author signature issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52425454/9902220)

Comment: Thanks, think that is what I need.